# Fire JavaScript event with custom parameter and catch it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-events

I'm currently firing a custom JavaScript event like that from the page itself to the iframe document:

```
// Create iframe
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'URL to load');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// Event itself
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.custom = 'example param';
event.initEvent('custom', false, true);
iframe.contentWindow.window.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Now on this iframe page I have jQuery available. How could I catch the event (which works) and also (important) get the custom (object) parameter?

Catching it like that:

```
$(document).on('custom', function(e, param) {
    alert(e); // [object Object] -> normal jQuery event data without any special data
    alert(e.custom); // undefined
    alert(param); // undefined
});
```

How could I get the custom parameter data without adding jQuery to the page itself which contains the iframe?

Comment: `Document.createEvent('')` is deprecated -- it would probably be better to use `new Event('')` or `new CustomEvent('', {})` -- see [MDN: Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FCreating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery wraps the original DOM event. The original event should be available through the `originalEvent` property of the jQuery event.

```
e.originalEvent.custom
```

should evaluate to your custom value, in this case `'example param'`.

Comment: edits must be at least 6 characters.. apparently 1 letter and 5 spaces doesn't count.

Comment: It does when you're the owner ;) Thanks for the hint.